# Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()". Despite using resolve for sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, assert, sinon-chai

I am trying to assert on AddressesController that is making a get call from a scanner that is stubbed. But I kept getting the error below.

Tried supplying done into it('', (done) => {})

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. 
Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both
```

Don't really know what I am doing wrong as I'm pretty new to sinon-chai testing.

```
Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" 
is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

```
const assert = require('assert');
const moment = require('moment');
const config = require('config');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const scanner = require('../../modules/scanner');

const scannerStub = sinon.stub(scanner, 'getReport');
describe('verifyByOTP()', () => {
    before(async () => {
      scannerStub.reset();
    });
    
    it('should be success to verify address by OTP', async () => {
      const verifiedOTPUser = 'user';
      const address = '17W8yHeDqN6gZT';
      const response = {
        id: 'ff9bf0b0-218f-4995-8011-366e516a5765',
        error: null,
        risk_score: null,
        risk_score_detail: { source: null, destination: null },
      };
      scannerStub.resolves(response);

      const whitelistedAddress = await AddressesController.verifyByOTP(verifiedOTPUser, address);

      assert.notStrictEqual(whitelistedAddress.activatedAt, null);
      assert.strictEqual(whitelistedAddress.status, 'PENDING');
      assert.strictEqual(whitelistedAddress.address, address);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `it('...', async (done) => {` and then after last `assert.strictEqual(...); done();`?

Comment: @Molda Yeah tried that gave me a `
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
    at Context.it (test/controllers/AddressesController.test.js:580:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Comment: I guess you need to mock the actual GET request that happens in the `verifyByOTP` method instead of really performing it. If the call is performed in the scanner `getReport` method then I think what happens is that the method gets stubbed *too late* meaning that when Mocha starts running test cases it loads the `AddessesController` before the scanner `getReport` method gets stubbed -so the solution in that case would be to either pass the scanner as a parameter to the `verifyByOTP` method OR to play with the `require` order to stub the scanner method before it's imported in the controller file

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I tried your suggestion and move scanner import above the import of AddressController and I added console.log in scanner. Can verify that scanner was not called as console.log did not print both before and after the move.